# Undefined variable error during splitting views.py into modules - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-module

My codes in `views.py` becomes larger day by day, and now I want to split it into modules. But I have trouble with variables. Problem is in that I don't where should I declare variables, or import built-in modules: in my custom module, or `views.py`. Here is my codes:

`views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def result(request):
    find_by_fives()
    context = {
        'last_uploaded': last_uploaded,
        'words_count': words_count,
        'characters_count': characters_count
    }
    return render(request, 'result.html', context)
```

`find_by_fives.py`(is my custom module):

```
import glob 
from .models import OriginalDocument
from django.shortcuts import render

def find_by_fives():
    last_uploaded = OriginalDocument.objects.latest('id')

    original = open(str(last_uploaded.document), 'r')
    original_words = original.read().lower().split()
    words_count = len(original_words)

    open_original = open(str(last_uploaded.document), "r")
    read_original = open_original.read()
    characters_count = len(read_original)

    path = 'static/other_documents/doc*.txt'
    files = glob.glob(path)
```

Error: `NameError: name 'last_uploaded' is not defined`

Note: This is not my entire view, all I want to know is just where should I declare `context`, variables, and imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see - "find_by_fives.py" is a function, right? So the variables that you declare inside it lives only there. So when you call this function from the views.py - they get declared and then, when the function is over they get deleted. If you want to use them in the views.py - you should return them and assign a variable there, then pass them to the context:

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def result(request):
   last_uploaded, words_count, characters_count = find_by_fives()
   context = {
       'last_uploaded': last_uploaded,
       'words_count': words_count,
       'characters_count': characters_count
   }
   return render(request, 'result.html', context)

def find_by_fives():
   last_uploaded = OriginalDocument.objects.latest('id')

   original = open(str(last_uploaded.document), 'r')
   original_words = original.read().lower().split()
   words_count = len(original_words)

   open_original = open(str(last_uploaded.document), "r")
   read_original = open_original.read()
   characters_count = len(read_original)

   path = 'static/other_documents/doc*.txt'
   files = glob.glob(path) 
   return last_uploaded, words_count, characters_count
```

Comment: man, I ask just for taking advise. Is there another and easier method to do this process ? Because lots of returned variables, assigning all of them to the function seems not so good I think.

Comment: Well, you might do something like - declaring the variables in the 'result' function, and then passing them as parameter to the 'find_by_fives' and updating them there. In python, any variable is a pointer, so by passing them to this function, you are actually passing the address to this variable, so any modification to it in 'find_by_fives' function will be reflected in the 'result' function as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: Man, hello, have a good day. Can you check please my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156491/django-form-save-is-not-creating-modelform ? Last days my question reach very few people, and can't tag someone. Please, help me.